# Getting the previous element in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `the_list = [[3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5], [4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`.How do I print the previous element from any randomly chosen element in the three lists in `the_list`. If the randomly chosen element is at index 0, then the previous element would be the element at the end of the list. For example, if I pick `rande = 3` for the list, then I will get the following output:

```
5
1
2
```

How do I code this in the whilst having the most efficient time complexity?

Comment: The best time complexity is obviously `O(nm)` where `n` is the number of lists and `m` is the length of the lists. What code have you tried?

Comment: what happens if `3` (three) isn't in any or anyone list ?

Comment: The "two" lists in `the_list`?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. `rande` element would always be in all the lists in `the_list`. @TigerhawkT3 sorry it was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `list.index()` method and take advantage of the fact that negative numbers index a `list` from the end:

```
>>> the_list = [[3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5], [4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
>>> rande = 3
>>> for subl in the_list:
...     print(subl[subl.index(rande)-1])
...
5
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for 3

l = [[3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5], [4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

>>> list(map(lambda x: x[(x.index(3) -1)],l))

[5, 1, 2]
```